# Rails 4 routes error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

We have shifted a project to **Rails4** from **Rails3** but some routes are not working.

Our previous route for rails 3 was

> match 'moon-signs'  =>  'promotions#moon_portal',   :as =>  :moon_portal_promotions

which used to work for both **GET** and **POST** requests. Now we have changed routes according to **Rails4** conventions and above route has become:

> match 'moon-signs' => 'promotions#moon_portal', :as => :moon_portal_promotions,
>    :via => [:get, :post]

Now our above route works for **'GET'** method but doesn't work for **'POST'** method. And rake routes show following route for above

> moon_portal_promotions  **GET|POST** /moon-signs(.:format)  **promotions#moon_portal**

Comment: it should work for POST as well. What's the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution though didn't expect it would be the issue.

Above route with following change worked for me.

> match '/moon-signs' => 'promotions#moon_portal', :as =>  :moon_portal_promotions,
>   :via => [:get, :post]

Only with addition of **/** in match has fixed the issue.